# Orientation of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is not responding properly

Tags: iphone, ios4, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I have used AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to show Only "Camera" & Augmented reality concept is placed on top of that by designing view. But i am facing problem of the orientation. When i change the orientation, view's orientation works properly but camera view orientation behaves weirdly. Generally camera view show 90 degree shifted view. I have changed the orientation in shouldAutoRotate method for BOTH i.e View & Camera but sometimes it work fine & sometimes behaves weird. Please guide me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually My overlay view orientation & Camera orientation were conflicting initially thats why behaved weird. now got the rid of that & working it smoothly.

Comment: Can you kindly explain your solution a little deeper and perhaps provide some code for those who haven't solved it?  Thank you.